# Converting multiband raster to polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, raster-conversion, multi-band

I'm currently using ArcMap 10.8

I want to convert a Multiband Raster with 3 band with each band represent the RGB value, so I can calculate the area of ​​each value (classification) in a smaller regional area.

[image] [image]

Unfortunately, when i'm using the raster to polygon conversion tool, the output only has the Red Band(Band1) Value. This is very clearly visible from the distribution of output values, which is very different from the initial data multiband raster.

[image] [image]

The classification of red values ​​in the output only represents one value (255), but still produces a dominance distribution of red

Is there another method to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting a single-band pseudocolor image into an RGB image and then performing classification statistics? If so, it's recommended to work directly on the single-band image, as there are many simpler methods available. If you only have an RGB image to start with, you'll need a color mapping table that records the R, G, and B values corresponding to each class. Then, using GDAL to read the raster data, you can determine which class each grid cell belongs to, calculate the total number of cells, compute the area of each cell, and finally, multiply the 'number of cells * cell area' to calculate the total area.

Comment: Thankyou for the response! yes, I only have RGB image data, and sorry I don't have experience using GDAL so I don't really understand your response. but I have tried adding up the values for each band, and there are same values for colors that should be different (such as orange and light green). Do I have to classify it manually by looking at the value of each band in the attribute table?

Comment: R 、G、B 、value directly plus have  question ,for example :R:10\G:20\B:30 is same as R:30\G:20\B:10，but their colour is very different .

Comment: the method I give you is arcgis API for  JavaScript's method

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Combine](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) tool to create a single band raster with unique output values assigned to each unique combination of input values.

[image: Illustration]

Note you You need to add the bands to the tool separately, don't try to add the RGB raster itself.

[image]

Then you can polygonize on the unique output values. To get the RGB values into the polygon feature class, [join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) the combined raster attribute table to the polygon attribute table.

Comment: Thank You! This method provides better results, but the value results still do not show an accurate representation of the raster data. parts of the initial raster data that were previously orange and light green have the same value in the output using the combine method. maybe because the initial raster has the same combination of band values (such as 70-30-1 in orange while 30-70-1 in light green) which causes the output value calculations to be the same?

Comment: I've never seen that. The doc shows that (for example) 0, 1 will get a different output value than 1, 0. Ensure that you entered the bands correctly.

Comment: Yes, I entered each band correctly. The output values do get different numbers, but after looking at the spatial distribution of the values, many of the class levels are mixed up, especially in the orange-yellow-light green colors, which may be greatly influenced by the results of mixing values between bands. Meanwhile, the spatial distribution of dominant colors such as dark red and dark green has shown very good similarity to the initial raster data.

Comment: Are you comparing visually? Is the RGB using a stretched renderer? If so, that will be misleading. Have you actually sampled a number of points from each to compare?

Comment: I compared them visually after classifying the values into several classes with equal intervals, and yet the distribution in some locations of orange and light green has been mixed up, even though orange should have a higher value than light green because dark red is already at the highest value and dark green is at the lowest value, right?

Comment: I used combine on an RGB image (satellite image), then [sampled](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/sample.htm) the RGB values from the original image and the output of the combine and got exactly the same values.